# Using .has() with keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the `.has()` selector to only execute key controls when my body has an image.

This is what I'm trying at the moment but it's not working.

```
if ($('body').has('img')){
   $(document).on('keyup', function (event) {
     if (event.which === 37) {
       console.log('test');
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: is it IE? If so change event to ev or something else because event is a global object in IE.

Comment: `if($('img').length)` is much simplier. Or `body img` if needed.

Comment: `.has()` returns a jQuery object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, read `.length` property of the returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather check if image is there using plain selector:

```
if ($('img').length) {
   $(document).on('keyup', function (event) {
     if (event.which === 37) {
       console.log('test');
     }
   });
}
```

Here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/yXqJE/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if ($('body img').length) {
}
```

Comment: Why would that work if the OP's `$('body').has('img')` doesn't?

Comment: Because `$('body').has('img')` will return `array` with elements or empty which will be always truthy

Comment: Yes, I was sort of hoping to prompt you to edit that information into your answer... (Though it doesn't return an array, it returns a jQuery object.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to register the hanlder to body element and the image condition is dynamic then

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'body:has(img)', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 37) {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'body', function (event) {
    if($(this).find('img').length) {
       if (event.which === 37) {
           console.log('test');
       }
    }
});
```